# Can you limit the records count for each user Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

Can you set a database constraint to allow the users to add only a specific amount of records that have the a specific value field?
Example:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
      ('1', '1'),
      ('2', '2'),
      ('3', '3'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    choice = models.Charfield(choices=CHOICES)
```

I want to allow each user to be able to add only 4 records with choice 3, is there a current way to do it at the database level?

Comment: you can make this inserting json on db

Comment: could you elaborate on this, I didn't fully get it. Also I'm not experienced in writing sql, I depend on the django orm for the db

Comment: make a json like "{"1": "amount", "2": "amount", "3": "amount"}", and insert this json in a postgresql database, with JSONfield

Comment: did u understand?

Comment: you mean to remove the second model and save the data instead in json field on the user model? the user could have only a specified amount of records in the Example table while selecting the choice 3, I could filter on save and get the count and raise an error if the count is greater than allowed, but I want to set the constraint on the db, something like unique_together.

Comment: @LucasBorges-Santos, what happend?